# using typearea and octavo to create Golden-Ratio-compliant books at lulu.com

Tags: koma-script, layout, dimensions, octavo

I have a number of books with various page counts that I want to have printed and bound by [lulu.com](https://lulu.com), and I'd like to make them as Golden-Ratio-compliant as I can. In order to do this, I'm using the `octavo` class and the `typearea` package in `KOMA-script`, but the documentation has my head spinning so hard that so far Stack Exchange hasn't been able to clear it up.

I'm using Garamond Premier Pro font in 10, 11, or 12-point size and `DIV=classic` as a `typearea` setting. The font is not negotiable, but the sizes and the DIV setting are. The paper will be 60#. I can bind in hardcover or paperback. The paper-size options Lulu offers are as follows:

[image]

What I'd like to know is:

1. What trim size(s) would be best for me to use?
2. Assuming that I don't have any similar books to measure against, what calculation(s)/rule(s) of thumb can I use to set BCOR?
3. What other class options should I use for `typearea`?
4. Are there any other adjustments/settings I should make?

I've tried to make this question clear but, as I say, my head is spinning, so if I can make it clearer or better in any way or add more appropriate tags please let me know and I'll happily do it.

Comment: Is KOMA the right approach?  IIRC it uses an entirely different theory for ideal sizes.  Good old geometry would do a better job of achieving specific aspect ratios.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Ah! Okay! Thank you so much! I'm a pretty inexperienced LaTeXer, so I didn't know about this. I'll go check it out.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I was following the second answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33895/what-paper-dimensions-to-use-for-printing-with-the-octavo-class